# Android LinearLayout cannot add multiple views program

Tags: android, layout, view

I'm trying to add multiple customo views (for now they are simple rectangles) using this code

```
            //Defining the layout

    HandLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    HandLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    HandLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_hand));
    HandLayout.setLayoutParams(new   LayoutParams(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_hand_width), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_hand_height)));


            //Some more code

    int dx = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_cardslot_width);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        Card c = new Card(this,i);
        HandLayout.addView(c);  
        c.setX(i*dx);
    }
```

The problem is that instead of getting 6 rectagles one next to the other I only see the first rectangle.

I think the rectangles are there but are "behind" the first drawn rectangle. How do I tell the view to "move" them dx to the right?

Thanks for any help

EDIT: The problem is with the Card Class code, I think. After a suggestion from one of the user I've tried adding TextViews and they worked. Here is the code for the card class (NOTE the only code not present are the declarations of a bunch of constant ints).

```
public Card(Context context, int id) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    borders = new Rect(0,0,
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_cardslot_width),
            getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_cardslot_height));

    offw = (getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_cardslot_width) - getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_card_width))/2;
    offh = (getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_cardslot_height) - getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_card_height))/2;

    cborders = new RectF((float)offw, (float)offh, 
            (float)getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_card_width), 
            (float)getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dim_card_height));

    ntext = Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE,Typeface.NORMAL);
    paint = new Paint();
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_card));
    canvas.drawRect(borders, paint);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_card));
    canvas.drawRoundRect(cborders, rad, rad, paint);

    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.card_text));
    paint.setTextSize(14);
    canvas.drawText("Card: " + String.valueOf(ID),offw,TopOffset+CharHeight,paint);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your layouts are not off screen to the right as you have a horizontal orientation set.

Comment: My layout is color coated (so I can see where it stats and where it ends) It has the exact size I specified it. Now it is possible for the Views to be to the left off the screen (the card shown is on the left side of the screen). But, how do check/fix this?

Comment: can you also put an image of your output

Answer (score 1):

They are not "behind", they are "next" to each other, the width of every view i think is fill_parent this is why you get only one view, try to put your parent layout inside a `scrollView` and check the difference

Comment: I don't think this is it. The width of the HandLayout is 6 times the width of the card view. Adding 6 views should show one rectangle beside the other as there is enough space. I can see the color of the layout after the rectangle ends. So there is plenty of space. I've also tried HandLayout.addView(c,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); and it is the same. I'll try though.

Comment: try removing the setX() line, the linearlayout will put your views horizontally you wont need a setX() method, also just to verify, try adding just buttons to your layout and see if they will show up

Comment: The original code did not have the setX line. I've added it because I kept seeing only the one card. I'll try with buttons.

Comment: It worked. I changed the card for a simple TextView and the words are are shown one beside the other. So what does this mean? I'll post the code of the class

Comment: you could ignore this whole view class, and make an XML layout as your view, and then just inflate it and make modifications, and add it to the layout, this is how I would do it

Comment: But the thing is I want a Card Class because not only will it contain information on how to draw itself but also other information that the program will need. Is what you are telling me compatible with the idea of creating a class card? The Card class will be inherited by several other classes and List<Card> will be used for all of the programs real functions. This is why I want to do it this way....

Comment: I think so because i'm not used to draw my views programmaticly, you could assign you infos as you inflate the view, I think it would be the same

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do this. To be honest I don't understand and/or know XML so I wanted to avoid it as much as possible...

Answer (score -1):

XML solution:

Let's say your card design is represented as follows

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
   View cardView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.xml_above, null);
   TextView tv = cardView.findViewById(R.id.value));
   tv.setText("your text");

   //if you have click listeners
   tv.setOnClickListener(...);

   HandLayout.addView(cardView); 

}
```

as simple as it looks

Comment: Thank you. However I still don't understand. What I want to do is draw a rectangle of specific dimensions. Inside that rectangle is another colored rectangle and inside that several lines of monospace text in the middle (centered) and below that a single line of values all of which will vary from card to card. Where, in your code, do I tell the TextView to be drawn as I want it to? Just to be clear the card Is drawn as I want it to. However I commented the code and did not included it.

Comment: I believe you can achieve this by making different xml layouts (as shown above) of your different items (rectangles as linearlayout/relativelayout...), and then inflate them one by one according to your needs, I know it seems complex, and I don't see a better way

Comment: Ohh ok. Then its not going to work. When the program is done I need to define around 600 cards (from a text file). My Idea was to inherit the class and draw then according to text file instructions. There has got to be a way to draw two rectangles and get them to show beside each other.....

Comment: leave the card info in a class you define, but for the drawing part leave it to xml